# Compare page url optimize in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Rehub Theme

I want to change comparison page url from domain.com/comparison/?compareids=224,279,228 to domain.com/comparison/product1-vs-product2-vs-product3 or something similar.

Any idea how to achieve this

Tried this

```php
// Replace product IDs with names in comparison URL
function replace_comparison_url($url) {
    if (isset($_GET['compareids'])) {
        $product_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_GET['compareids']));
        $product_slugs = array();

        foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
            $product_slug = get_product_slug_by_id($product_id); // Custom function to get product slug by ID

            if ($product_slug) {
                $product_slugs[] = $product_slug;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($product_slugs)) {
            $new_url = home_url('/test/comparison/');
            $new_url .= '?compare=' . implode(',', $product_slugs);

            return $new_url;
        }
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_compare_list_url', 'replace_comparison_url');


// Custom function to get product slug by ID (replace this with your actual implementation)
function get_product_slug_by_id($product_id) {
    // Your logic to get the product slug by ID

    // For example:

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    return $product ? $product->get_slug() : '';
}
```